# reaching the 'tag' property of sender object

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have created an `IBAction` like this: `-(IBAction) buttonTapped:(id)sender;` and connected it to a `UIButton` using interface builder, the problem is that I can't do something like `NSLog(@"%d",sender.tag);` the compiler gives me syntax error that the tag property does not exist in object of type `id` ... but however when I do something like `NSLog(@"%@", sender);` the console displays info about the button and **its tag** ... so the question is: how can I reach the tag property of the `UIButton` through the sender object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried casting `sender`? For example:

```
NSLog(@"%d", ((UIButton *)sender).tag);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast it, because the compiler does not know the type of object (hence the id type), but the runtime will know.

So, it's similar to :

```
NSLog(@"%d", [(UIButton*)sender tag]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of casting, it often makes for cleaner code just to be more specific in your action declaration:

```
 -(IBAction) buttonTapped:(UIButton*)sender;
```

You can use UIButton, UIControl, UIView or whatever level of specificity you require.